# Finding out the version of Edge browser

Tags: microsoft-edge

If I go to settings of the Edge browser on my Windows 10 computer, it shows me the version of the Edge browser as follow:

**Microsoft Edge 44.17763.831.0**

**Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.17763**

What is now the version of my Edge browser? Is that 44 or 18?

And in either cases, why is this page showing that MS Edge has versions up to 80 ???

https://caniuse.com/#search=custom%20properties

Is my MS Edge version 36 respectively 62 versions behind?? :-)

Comment: If you think my suggestion can be the answer to this question then I suggest you accept it as an answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Edge **44.17763.831.0** is your **MS Edge browser** version.

Microsoft EdgeHTML **18.17763** is the version of **EdgeHTML** engine which is used by the MS Edge browser.

This is the MS Edge browser which by default comes with Windows 10 OS.

[image]

You said documentation **page showing that MS Edge has versions up to 80**.

Recently, Microsoft had launched MS Edge Browser based on the Chromium engine. Which is using these numbers as per Chromium engine.

[image]

You can download the new MS Edge Chromium browser from the link below. It is free to download and use and the user can install it on most of the Windows OS, Android OS, and MAC OS. It comes with many exciting, new and useful features.

[Download MS Edge Chromium browser](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download)

You had asked, "**Is my MS Edge version 36 respectively 62 versions behind?? :-)**"

No, Both MS Edge (EdgeHTML) browser and MS Edge (Chromium) browser are two different browsers. You are using MS Edge (EdgeHTML) browser. I suggest you update your Windows OS to update your MS Edge EdgeHTML browser.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `caniuse` site is using build numbers not version numbers, there's a little more information here (but there's more information elsewhere I'd imagine) ...

https://venturebeat.com/2015/09/21/microsoft-details-edge-version-numbers-one-for-the-app-and-one-for-the-engine/